# Moving a mysql innodb data partition from one computer to the other

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-9.04, innodb, mysql

/etc/mysql/conf.d/myserver:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table
datadir          = /elastidb/lib/mysql
#log-bin          = /elastiblockdb/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log

general_log      = true
log = /elastiblockdb/log/mysql/mysql_general.log

log-error        = /elastiblockdb/log/mysql/mysql_error.log
max_binlog_size  = 1000M
log-slow-queries = /elastiblockdb/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time  = 10
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4500M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 200M
innodb_log_file_size = 64M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
```

i have two identical ubuntu machine on amazon servers. two of the machines have identical /etc/mysql configuration files. the problem is that when i unmount /elastidb (mysql data) on one server and remount it on the other, when i try to start mysql on the other server i get the following error:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
091104 13:53:13 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
091104 13:53:14  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
091104 13:53:14 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

when i remove the directive datadir from my configuration file then mysql server starts but without loading the appropriate db data from my desired location.

I want to be able to quickly move that mysql data storage from one machine to the other. what may be the problem ?

both machines are on ubuntu 9.04 jaunty 64 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Does the `mysql/plugin.frm` error occur on both machines? My guess is so.

   Did the datadir come from a pre-5.1 installation? Run `mysql_upgrade` to get rid of this.
2. Even when using `innodb_file_per_table` MySQL will still create a single shared tablespace.

   The lack of `innodb_data_home_dir` and `innodb_data_file_path` variables in the config you're provided should mean that a 10M auto-extending tablespace is created under your `datadir`. But if the second machine is complaining about it missing then it suggests that maybe it isn't under your `datadir`.

   I'd suggest having a hunt around for this file (`ibdata1`) on the first (working) machine. If it exists outside the `datadir`, then shutdown MySQL, move it and configure those variables.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (same error message, but on Ubuntu server 10.04, and I changed the mysql datadir to point at /opt/mysql).

The problem was that apparmor was blocking attempts by /usr/sbin/mysqld to read /opt/mysql.  I found lines like:

```
type=1503 audit(1291916635.209:18):  operation="open" pid=1201 parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" requested_mask="r::" denied_mask="r::" fsuid=105 ouid=105 name="/opt/mysql/mysql/plugin.frm"
mysql main process (928) terminated with status 1
```

In my /var/log/syslog.

I edited /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld, replacing all instances of '/var/lib/mysql' with '/opt/mysql'.

After that mysql started properly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was apparmor. Since my machine is purposed for testing only, I chose the simplest way for solving it:

```
apt-get remove apparmor
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql/plugin.frm
is a file that store in over data folder
if u use to link mysql link
c:\programdata\mysql\mysql server 5.1\data\dir
if file not found then u reinstall the mysql
it is visual basic file